# Corda service does not exist when running flow tests with a MockNetwork

Tags: corda

I have a CorDapp where I define an oracle. The oracle works fine when running the nodes normally. However, when running flow tests using a MockNetwork, I get the following exception:

> net.corda.core.flows.FlowException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Corda service
>   net.corda.option.oracle.oracle.Oracle does not exist

How can I register the Corda service with the `MockNetwork` or get it to recognise it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initialising the `MockNetwork`, you must pass the package where the service is defined as one of the CorDapp packages to scan. So in your case, you would write:

```
private val mockNet: MockNetwork = MockNetwork(
    cordappPackages = listOf("net.corda.option.oracle.oracle")
)
```

Comment: I am getting same error when i run cordapp locally on i tried updating NodeDriver.kt 

driver(isDebug = true, extraCordappPackagesToScan = listOf("com.example.services"))

it doesn't help

Comment: I am using corda V2 How can i update cordapp that it runs locally on network created from NodeDriver.kt and it doesn't throw this exception!

Comment: This question is about the `MockNetwork`. Can you raise a separate question about testing using the driver, please? :)

Comment: here is the question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704930/corda-service-does-not-exist-when-running-flow-local-network-created-by-driver