# Corda service does not exist when running flow on local network created by driver (NodeDriver.kt)

Tags: corda

I am getting following exception when accessing a service in flow of a cordapp

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Corda service
>   com.example.services.MyService does not exist

i am using cordaV2 and have tried to edit NodeDriver.kt with

> driver(isDebug = true, extraCordappPackagesToScan =
>   listOf("com.example.services"))

but it doesn't help.

How can i update cordApp code that it runs locally on network created from NodeDriver.kt and it doesn't throw this exception!

Comment: i have also tried adding my service as an advertised service under the deployNodes task in build.gradle  e.g. node { name "CN=NodeD,O=NodeD,L=New York,C=US" advertisedServices = ["com.example.services.MyService"] p2pPort 10014 rpcPort 10015 webPort 10016 cordapps = [] rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": []]] }

it also doesn't help

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://github.com/corda/oracle-example. The oracle is loaded fine when run from the node driver without having to set extra packages to scan. The problem must be elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I rechecked my code and realized i wasn't using ServiceHub parameter in my service class. After adding that it was fixed.

> class MyService(**val services: ServiceHub**) :
>   SingletonSerializeAsToken()